# c++ precision issue in storing floating point numbers

Tags: c++

I'm handling some mathematical calculation.
I'm losing precision. But i need extreme precision.
I then used to check the precision issue with the code given below.
Any solution for getting the precision?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc,char** arvx)
{
   float f = 1.00000001;
   cout << "f: " <<std::setprecision(20)<< f <<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output is
f: 1

Comment: Step 1 is to not use `float`. Use `double`, which has about 16 digits of precision and should always be your first choice for storing real numbers. Do you need more than 16 significant digits?

Comment: [Not if you store it in a double](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9dbfa7280e8f9d1) (Maybe boost::multiprecision would be good too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want *precise* representation of these sorts of numbers (ie, with very small fractional components many places beyond the decimal point), then floating point types like `float` or even the much more precise `double` may still not give you the exact results you are looking for in all circumstances. Floating point types can only approximate some values with small fractional components.

You may need to use some sort of high precision fixed point C++ type in order to get *exact* representation of very small fractions in your values, and resulting accurate calculated results when you perform mathematical operations on such numbers. The following question/answers may provide you with some useful pointers: [C++ fixed point library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945747/c-fixed-point-library)

Answer (score 0):

in c++

```
float f = 1.00000001;
```

support only 6 digits after decimal point

```
float f = 1.000001;
```

if you want more real calculation use double

Comment: in using double, 1.00000001 is shown as 1.0000000099999999392

Comment: @KiranJose [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: '6 digits after the decimal point' simply isn't correct. '6 decimal digits of total precision' would be more like it, but after the decimal point this can take much larger forms as you are dividing, not multiplying. Consider e.g. 2^-10.